# Discord bot normal user name from pc, but @invalid-user from phone

Tags: javascript, automation, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm currently creating a unique discord bot for one of my friends' server, and I've got a problem. The code looks like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
      if(message.content.startsWith(${prefix}kick)){
         if(message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS')){
              let member  = message.mentions.members.first();
```

the prefix is e$.

When I call this, it works correctly and the bot writes

```
back @member has been kicked.
```

From pc, I see the member's name mentioned, but from phone, I see

```
@invalid-user has been kicked.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda caused by Discord client as you're able to see the mention on PC but not on mobile. I've also experienced same so I decided to display member username instead of mention, you can use: `member.displayName` for that, additionally you can add *(ID: {id})* next to the name if you wish to.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but using this method, I get [object Object] (im using an array to make the response random) but I think I can figure out why that is. Thanks!